# Can anyone advice good materials for studying Ruby (starting from the very beginning)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner **Ruby** programmer and want to find a more efficient way of studying it, is it better reading a book or viewing tutorials?

can anyone propose any book or any efficient tutorial?

Comment: Do you know object oriented programming? I find that when a lot of people want to learn a new language they really want to learn OO programming principles. Once you've got those down, its fairly easy to pick up a new language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tryruby](http://tryruby.org/) - fun and simple

[Intoducing ruby](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/ruby?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=ruby-alpha&utm_source=Sailthru&utm_term=ruby-alpha-tester) - ruby courses from Codecademy

Comment: I'm so happy that Codecademy added Ruby!

Answer (score 2):

I learned from Lynda.com with Kevin Skoglund

[Ruby course at lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-tutorials/essential-training/47905-2.html)

It is a great course and will give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

[The Well Grounded Rubyist](http://www.manning.com/black2/)

[Ruby Essentials](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Essentials)

[Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) (outdated stuff, but still its worth a read as the basics never get outdated)

Answer (score 2):

I think a great book is a solid way to start, just read and re read that book from back to front and do all of the challenges (i would strongly recommend a book that has them) and then you can start branching out. Below is how i got started.

[Learn to Program by Chris Pine](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/) is brilliant for the uninitiated and had loads of questions to get you thinking properly.

Then progressed to [Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) which was great because you made a very simple version of twitter and are introduced to the rails framework.

[Codeschool](http://www.codeschool.com/) is awesome, its not just rails school but they have about 7 or 8 great rails related courses that cover things from testing, rails basics, rails best practices and even have a try ruby course and now a more advanced ruby bits course.

And finally i would always recommend [Railscasts.com](http://www.railscasts.com) Ryan Bates has covered soo much its an invaluable resource.

Enjoy Ruby!

Answer (score 1):

If you interested in Ruby On Rails, then Tutorial (really more like a book) from Michael Hartl is great: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is "better" to learn by books or examples is rather subjective (as is the question). Some people learn better with books, others by tinkering with examples. Do both and you will quickly find out which way you prefer.

But more importantly than learning a new language, is learning how to learn a new language. This is true for most skills.

Before asking a question like this, I would start by searching what's already out there on google, wikipedia, and stackoverflow.

Such as: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=best+ruby+tutorial&submit=search

Which quickly turns up these related questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-ruby

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549394/whats-a-good-book-for-learning-ruby

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124371/what-is-the-best-ruby-tutorial-online

You will notice that 2/3 of these were closed as "not constructive".

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to follow an online course where you can interact with other people.

A good course I've attended is http://rubylearning.org/classes/

It's not free, it costs nearly 20$